# How to find out what time of day people visit your Facebook business page?

Tags: webapp-rec

I read in the [Facebook Pages Product Guide](http://ads.ak.facebook.com/ads/FacebookAds/Pages_Product_Guide_022812.pdf):

> "Find out when (a.k.a. what times of day) people visit each of the sites most often, so that you
>   can post before they visit the site."
>
> "We have found that people visit and engage with Pages most often
>   between 9pm and 10pm, with the 18-24 age group being the most
>   active."

I'm not entirely certain that our demographic is just ages 18-24, and I want to find out on average when people visit our Facebook pages the most.

Is there some existing tool I can hook into the Facebook API to find this information out?  Or even some sort of graph that shows when people visit the page in more detail?

I discovered that you can get a lot of raw metrics data by entering the *Insights Dashboard* and clicking *Export*, but none of it appears to be related to "time of day" type stuff.

Comment: Theoretically (never tried it) you could point all users to a landing page and add Google Analytics to that canvas. There will be no way to track other sections of your page though.

Comment: I know that when users post comments on the FB Business Page, I get notification emails.  Is it possible that I could use an email client addon/extension to tally up and then average the times that users post comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook does not offer an option to view who views your Facebook page. So you will not be able to definitively associate viewers to names. However you can make good guesses by implementing these strategies:

- Facebook bases their search bar searches off of the people that visit your business profile. If you type the letter "G", then whatever appears first below, most likely viewed your profile
- You can provide a link to your Facebook page from another site, and track the IP Address, and redirect the viewer to your Facebook page. With the IP Address you can use location tracking, with website services such as [IP 2 Location](http://ip2location.com) and guess who lives in the area.

Comment: I'm not concerned with who visits the page so much as I am concerned with at what time of day they visit the page...rephrasing my question...

Comment: Facebook does not allow access to what time of day users view your profile. Once again, the best way to determine that metric is through redirecting users from your own link and logging the time of day.

Comment: So like bit.ly then?  I tried bit.ly for tracking that sort of thing, but you still have to be present within the specified 24 hour period or the data gets lost.

Comment: I would sign up for a free web host at http://www.000webhost.com and put this php script on the top level directory : http://pastebin.com/ApnKGZHv. It will create a file named `visitor_times.txt` containing the time/dates that your facebook page was clicked on.

Comment: The script doesn't seem to have much in the way of file locking, makes me a little concerned that it might miss visitors in the very unlikely event that two of them should hit the page at the same time, but it's a start.  Thank you.